# solving circular imports using __init__.py within 1 package python

Tags: python, import, sys.path

I have 2 files which are in a package and it would be convenient to pull 1-2 funcs from each into the other. In **init**.py I tried:

```
from mappings import *
from get_models import *
```

In mappings.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys, re

sys.path.append('/home/cchilders/scripts/python/work-tasks/unit_tests_scripts/completed')

from . import get_model_name_or_None
```

In get_models.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, re, sys

sys.path.append('/home/cchilders/scripts/python/work-tasks/unit_tests_scripts/completed')

from . import process_model
```

and instead of a namespace conflict or whatnot, I actually get:

```
[cchilders@localhost completed]$ ./mappings.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mappings.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import get_model_name_or_None
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

This surprised me, I was even paranoid enough about my package to append it to sys.path. When I try to import from 1 file to the other, without going through **init**.py and leaving init blank, my import works. I wonder:

1. How does python find packages in your file structure (this isn't a django app, just regular folder)? So was my appending to sys.path unnecessary?
2. Why can I not throw names into the package namespace and import them in each separate module? I even tried changing

`from mappings import *`
`from get_models import *`

to more safe `from get_models import get_model_name_or_None`  and I get exact same error as above

Thank you

With my **init**.py empty, and mappings.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys, re
```

(init empty, not appending my path, not trying any imports in mappings, get_model is importing a function from mappings correctly) I get:

```
[cchilders@localhost completed]$ python -m mappings.py
*correct output*
/usr/bin/python: No module named mappings.py
```

The *correct output* is the code running as before (as expected), but I get the warning no module. Weirdly, when I uncomment my append:

```
sys.path.append('/home/cchilders/scripts/python/work-tasks/unit_tests_scripts/completed')
```

I still get the exact same correct output followed by warning `/usr/bin/python: No module named mappings.py`

Trying to use mappings in get_models is also difficult:

1. using `import mappings` with an empty init causes `NameError: name 'mappings' is not defined`
2. using `import mappings` with `import mapping` also in my init causes same `NameError: name 'mappings' is not defined`
3. using `import mappings` in my init but not in `get_models.py` and attempting to call `mappings.process_model` in `get_models` yields: `NameError: global name 'mappings' is not defined`

Comment: Instead of doing `./mappings.py` which is equivalent to `python mappings.py` , can you try `python -m mappings.py`?

Comment: Didn't get your last comment. However, you should avoid wild card imports in `__init__.py`. Import the module and use the functions as `module.function`

Comment: yes sir, it is at the bottom after "With my init empty..."

Comment: Sorry, The just wanted to see what happens when you try the `-m` option in the same situation as before. But you seem to have misplaced some code.